# Why are my POSTed files not getting to server?

Tags: post, apache2

Sending POST method files to server no files. It seems some people elude to me needing a script to "parse" the file however as I understand a POST, the file should POST and be copied to the apache server, even if I do nothing with it, correct?

I have tried numerous solutions from modifying .htaccess, php.ini and apache2.conf.

Currently I have

Apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
   RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.xml -f
   RewriteRule (.*) $1.xml [L]
  </IfModule>

 Options FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All
 Require all granted
</Directory>
```

.htaccess

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

php.ini (upload_tmp_dir not sure to put full path or from web root. I have also read to put it in quotes)

```
file_uploads = On
upload_tmp_dir = /var/www/html/eSCL/ScanJobs
```

Web root is /var/www/html
I want to upload to /var/www/html/eSCL/ScanJobs
Permissions for Scan jobs folder is 777
Owner www-data (appropriate for ubuntu)

Errors from 2 posts are 404 , one is CURL for testing , other is Mopria Android app for scanning.

CURL

```
curl -v -X POST -d @scansettings.xml  
http://localhost:80/eSCL/ScanJobs
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> POST /eSCL/ScanJobs HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 605
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 605 out of 605 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Thu, 16 May 2019 17:14:32 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
< Content-Length: 286
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /eSCL/ScanJobs was not found on this server. 
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Apache log entry for above CURL request

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2019:12:14:32 -0500] "POST /eSCL/ScanJobs HTTP/1.1" 404 447 "-" "curl/7.47.0"
```

in Apache log using Mopria (including successful hits)

```
192.168.0.8 - - [16/May/2019:12:17:59 -0500] "GET /eSCL/ScannerStatus HTTP/1.1" 200 716 "-" "okhttp/3.9.1"
192.168.0.8 - - [16/May/2019:12:18:04 -0500] "GET /eSCL/ScannerStatus HTTP/1.1" 200 715 "-" "okhttp/3.9.1"
192.168.0.8 - - [16/May/2019:12:18:09 -0500] "GET /eSCL/ScannerStatus HTTP/1.1" 200 715 "-" "okhttp/3.9.1"
192.168.0.8 - - [16/May/2019:12:18:13 -0500] "GET /eSCL/ScannerCapabilities HTTP/1.1" 200 1389 "-" "okhttp/3.9.1"
192.168.0.8 - - [16/May/2019:12:18:13 -0500] "GET /eSCL/ScannerStatus HTTP/1.1" 200 715 "-" "okhttp/3.9.1"
192.168.0.8 - - [16/May/2019:12:18:16 -0500] "GET /eSCL/ScannerStatus HTTP/1.1" 200 716 "-" "okhttp/3.9.1"
192.168.0.8 - - [16/May/2019:12:18:20 -0500] "GET /eSCL/ScannerCapabilities HTTP/1.1" 200 1389 "-" "okhttp/3.9.1"
192.168.0.8 - - [16/May/2019:12:18:20 -0500] "GET /eSCL/ScannerStatus HTTP/1.1" 200 715 "-" "okhttp/3.9.1"
192.168.0.8 - - [16/May/2019:12:18:25 -0500] "POST /eSCL/ScanJobs HTTP/1.1" 404 506 "-" "okhttp/3.9.1"
192.168.0.8 - - [16/May/2019:12:18:25 -0500] "GET /eSCL/ScannerStatus HTTP/1.1" 200 715 "-" "okhttp/3.9.1"
192.168.0.8 - - [16/May/2019:12:18:30 -0500] "GET /eSCL/ScannerStatus HTTP/1.1" 200 715 "-" "okhttp/3.9.1"
192.168.0.8 - - [16/May/2019:12:18:35 -0500] "GET /eSCL/ScannerStatus HTTP/1.1" 200 715 "-" "okhttp/3.9.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your document root is /var/www/ but I think it should /var/www/html.

Furthermore the curl request to test is

> curl -v -F "file=@img.jpg" http://localhost/index.php

And of course the uploaded file is temporarily put in

> /var/www/html/eSCL/ScanJobs/

so you have to move it with

> move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"eSCL/".$file_name);

or whatever folder you want.

Check my configuration below, the 200 response code from curl and the print_r($_FILES) where you see the temporary path of the upload file.

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
   RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.xml -f
   RewriteRule (.*) $1.xml [L]
  </IfModule>

 Options FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All
 Require all granted
</Directory>

curl -v -F "file=@img.jpg" http://localhost/index.php
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> POST /index.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 1238948
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------98473343d22dab8a
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 16 May 2019 21:29:01 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Length: 282
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => img.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /var/www/html/eSCL/ScanJobs/phpZBF3Cc
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 1238763
        )

)
test
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Comment: I am not concerned with MOVING the file at this point, only RECEIVING it.

Comment: there is a Virtual host 000-default.conf  what is applied to /var/www also aplies to all virtual hosts. This is the default install on Ubuntu. Sorry for not< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Thu, 16 May 2019 23:39:21 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
< Content-Length: 296
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
* HTTP error before end of send, stop sen clarifying that. I tried your command, and although it claimed to upload something the first time , no file was received.  The second time it just failed

Comment: I don't know which Ubuntu release you have installed but the default of 18.04 is /var/www/html but that does not matter if it is a well configured apache configuration.
One more thing that possible is wrong is the variable upload_tmp_dir = that you declared in php.ini.
Check if it setup properly and in the correct php.ini ( /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini  in my case)
If you phpinfo() you will see if the variable is initialized to the declared path or not.

Comment: Yes my upload path is similar path with except 7.0 instead of 7.2  , it shows in phpinfo corretly